# Edit mp3 in c# on a uploaded file from asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, audio, mp3

I would like to know how I could edit mp3 files on the server once it was uploaded from the user browser.

I am going to use a windows service on the server to process it, which is basically cut a specific piece of the mp3 uploaded by the user given the start and end period of time..

Is there any native .net library to do that? do I need third party libraries?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example from Stackoverflow:
[Trim an Audio File(.wav,.mp3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465863/trim-an-audio-file-wav-mp3)

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but it is a good starting point.