# How to cancel SpeechSynthesizer from writing to file, while keeping the audio that was produced?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, text-to-speech, speechsynthesizer

I am trying to write the output of `SpeechSynthesizer` to a .wav file. If the synthesis is completed, everything works well and the output file is playable;

```
AudioStream = new FileStream(CurAudioFile, FileMode.Create);  
reader.SetOutputToWaveStream(AudioStream);
reader.SpeakAsynch(myPromptBuilder);
```

But if I cancel the synthesis to the file through the following code (because the process is too long and I may want to cancel it) the output file produces no sound! (the produced file is not zero in size but nothing is played).

```
// On Cancel Button Clicked
reader.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
while (reader.State == SynthesizerState.Speaking)
{
      Application.DoEvents();
}
// reader.SetOutputToNull();
AudioStream.Close();
```

I look for a solution in which I can cancel the audio generation, but the audio file can be played to the portion before it was canceled.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if `AsyncCancelAll` writes the correct ending to the stream or not, I'd recommend trying a flush before closing the stream:

```
reader.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
while (reader.State == SynthesizerState.Speaking)
{
      Application.DoEvents();
}
// reader.SetOutputToNull();
AudioStream.Flush();
AudioStream.Close();
```

If that doesn't work, then I'd say explore the API guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakasynccancelall(v=vs.110).aspx

If you can't find a suitable API-provided solution, you could consider the following:

1. Run the synthesis on a background thread
2. Track the start time and cancellation / finish time
3. Cancellation doesn't cancel the synthesis, but just marks down the time it was cancelled
4. Desired audio-length is roughly (finish time - start time)
5. When the synthesis is finished, you could save the stream and then trim it: [Trim an Audio File(.wav,.mp3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465863/trim-an-audio-file-wav-mp3)

It might not be pretty, but it would probably get the job done.

Comment: Thank you, flushing the stream doesn't work. You say that there is no way to cancel or force the synthesis to finish and get a valid stream? How about using a `NAudio.Wave.RawSourceWaveStream` for the output?

Comment: @Ahmad I'm not proficient enough with the speech synthesis system to properly answer that I'm afraid. Good luck!