# C# NAudio - Keep Last X Seconds Of Audio

Tags: c#, naudio

I have a project where audio is recorded at several sources, and the goal is to process X (user-defined) seconds of it through various methods (DSP as well as speech-to-text).

I'm using a MixingSampleProvider to collect all the sources into one "provider." I'm passing this to a NotifyingSampleProvider because it raises an event at each sample, and then passing that sample to my class that does the processing. I'm adding the float the NotifyingSampleProvider produces to the end of my "X second window" array (using Array.Copy to create a temp array with all but that last value, adding that last value, and copying the temp array back to the original) which I use for processing.

The obvious problem here is that it notifies (and that I'm locking and adding to the "X second window" array) for every single sample, or 44100 times a second. This leads to the audio being pretty much constantly locked so it can't be processed. There's got to be a more performant way to deal with this.

The one idea I had was a BufferedWaveProvider that **doesn't** get read from anywhere else, so it's always full (with DiscardOnOverflow = true of course). However A) this still requires a NotifyingSampleProvider to add to it periodically (you can't pass a provider to the BufferedWaveProvider for it to automatically read from) and I'd like to get away from such frequent (44100 Hz) function calls, and B) I understand that there's a limit to the BufferDuration length, which might be too small of a window (I don't recall what the limit is and I can't find anything online saying what it is).

How might I solve this problem? Using NAudio, how to I keep the last X seconds of audio accessible to a separate class at any time without using the NotifyingSampleProvider?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465863/trim-an-audio-file-wav-mp3

Comment: Hmm. Getting the location and then reading from there. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I wasn't able to pull anything satisfactory from that link Right now I'm using my first idea - a BufferedWaveProvider being added to in the NotifyingSampleProvider event - and it works, but I'm still not a fan of having 44100 function calls a second.

Comment: Yes, don't use NotifyingSampleProvider for this. Instead you'll get better performance by processing samples in blocks (e.g. 2056 samples at a time).

Comment: Can you give an example? I've really struggled with the whole idea of finding the last X seconds of a provider's data. The only one that I've seen that gives that kind of information at all is the BufferedWaveProvider, and one has to add samples to it directly - this works if sending directly from a microphone, but if I'm using a mixer or resampler before processing I don't know how to get the very end of the provider's buffer/data.